# How to take a json as input and produce 2 arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to take a JSON as input and produce 2 arrays, one contains only keys and the other contains only value. But if a key and value are numerically equal then that pair won't take place in these arrays. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over `key,values` of an object by using `Object.entries` and then check if key and value are diffrent, put them in the related array. like this:

```js
let obj = {a:5, b:6, c:3, '1':4,'2':2};
let keys = [] , values = [];
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key,value])=> {
    if(key != value){
        keys.push(key);
        values.push(value)
    }
});

console.log('keys:',keys);
console.log('values:', values);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, what you are asking, there are two builtin functions, that give you the keys and data are seperated, no looping needed.

- `Object.values` returns all values of an object ([mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values))
- `Object.keys` returns all keys of an object ([mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys))

It works with Objects and Arrays:

```js
var data = {a:1, b:2, c:3, '1':5,'2':'a'};
// just to visualisze the input data
console.info('data-object:', JSON.stringify(data));
// extracted keys
console.info('keys:',  Object.keys(data));
// extracted values
console.info('values:',  Object.values(data));

var list = [1,2,3,4];
// just to visualisze the input data
console.info('data-list:', JSON.stringify(list));
// extracted keys
console.info('keys:',  Object.keys(list));
// extracted values
console.info('values:',  Object.values(list));

var data2 = {"1":1, "2":2};
// just to visualisze the input data
console.info('data-list:', JSON.stringify(data2));
// extracted keys
console.info('keys:',  Object.keys(data2));
// extracted values
console.info('values:',  Object.values(data2));
```

Comment: Yes. But, var data = {"1":1, "2":2} if a key and value are numerically equal then that pair won't take place in these arrays.

Comment: @AlImranHossain I don't understand what  need. could you define the desired result for your example `{1:1, 2:2}`

Comment: input data = {a:5, b:6, c:3, '1':4,'2':2}; output= [ 6, 5, 4, 3 ] [ '1',  'a', 'b', 'c' ]

Comment: @AlImranHossain, loop through the created arrays and delete any items where the match.

Comment: @AlImranHossain I think you answer covers your question, or am I missing something, were you need something more?

Comment: No. got it @winner